# How to change service priorities in LInux server

Tags: linux

I need to configure my server for network and ssh service at first priority while starting the server. Can anybody give me the steps to reconfigure start up service priorities

Comment: Your question is far to vague

Comment: Sounds like they're asking for a reordering of the /etc/rc.d scripts.

Comment: This depends *a lot* on the distribution you're using.

Comment: First: Which Linux Distribution? Debian, SuSE or RedHat?

Second: What is wrong with the default start order? What are your specific problems?

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the point in the startup sequence where network configuration happens and `sshd` starts?
Why?

Typically networking happens after (local) filesystems are mounted and critical local daemons are up, and SSH  starts right (or very soon) after Networking.  I can't think of any reason to want to change it (and on many modern Linux or BSD systems you **CAN'T**: Startup script ordering is determined for you by the OS based on a dependency graph).